# Random Reboot!!! Lenovo thinkpad E14 Gen2 Intel

Tags: thinkpad, reboot, restart

**Observed Behavior:** Laptop reboots at random times while working

**Possible Cause:** Mostly happens when I press the power button to wake up from sleep and unlock the PC. I assume something related to the power button.

**Troubleshooting attempts Until Now:**

1. Same behavior Windows 10 latest release, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS latest update and POP os 20.04 LTS latest release. Clean Install no dual BOOT.
2. Updated Bios using windows 10 and updated all the drivers.
3. Hardware Diagnostic using lenovo service bridge and Lenovo Built-in Diagnostics Extended full tests. (Everything perfect no errors)
4. sfc /scannow in windows 10 found some corrupt files and fixed them but did not fix the problem of reboot.
5. Sent the laptop back and ordered a new replacement laptop. Problem Present in the new laptop as well. So i assume the issue might be with lenovo drivers.

[**Laptop Specification:**](https://psref.lenovo.com/Product/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_E14_Gen_2_Intel?MT=20TB)

Comment: So steps 1-4 should be ignored? They apply to a different computer you no longer have. After a "sudden shutdown", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Comment: @waltinator thanks for the comment The log is too long to post here. Is there a way? The laptop does not feel hot Though and mainly reboots when wakes up from a suspend. When I lock and unlock it doesn't reboot

Comment: Read the log, line-by-line, paying attention to the timestamps. Messages from just before you noticed the problem may be interesting.